# How to call global function from promise function?

Tags: javascript, promise

When performing the below function:

```
        try {
            Auction.deployed().then(function(contractInstance) {
                contractInstance.startAuction(auctionname, duration, { from: buyerAddress }).then(function(result) {
                    console.log("AUCTION HAS STARTED!!");
                    console.log(result);
                    updateAuction(result.receipt);
                });
            });
        } catch (err) {}
    }
};

updateAuction = function(data) {
    console.log("UPDATE AUCTIONS!");
....
```

The updateAuction function is not called (even though the console.log functions are working correctly and displaying a message). How can I call the updateAuction function?

Comment: So you're saying  you get the `AUCTION HAS STARTED` log and a `result` that is not null/undefined, but not the log in `updateAuction`? And not getting any other error messages?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the order in which you're defining the promise and the function.

When you use the syntax `updateAuction = function () {}`, whether or not you use a `var`, you must define it above the promise code, otherwise it won't be available. This is in the same way that if you were to write the following, it wouldn't work:

```
var b = a;
var a = 'Hello!';
```

This seems quite obvious that `a` won't be available before it's defined. The same thing applies to functions:

```
var b = function () {
  a();
}
var a = function () {
  console.log('Hello');
}
```

The `b` function won't have access to `a`, because it's not yet defined.

If, however, you use the definition of `function updateAuction() {}`, it will be hoisted, meaning it is defined before anything else.

There are many articles regarding how hoisting works, for example [this one from scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript) and [this from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Comment: `var`s are hoisted also, and since promises execute after everything else, you can be assured that the function will have been defined.

Comment: Given that `then` callbacks are always asynchronous, the variable will have the function assigned when it is called.

Comment: In your second snippet, everything is fine as long as you call `b()` after the `a = …` assignment.

Comment: Hmmm.... yes maybe I am wrong. I wouldn't have thought that they would be hoisted. But I imagined that it isn't being called after it's defined/within the same scope. Tbh, it's hard to really know without the full code in the question.

Comment: Yeah you're right about the async hoisting, my bad, it's been a long day... http://jsbin.com/zexozac/edit?js,console - I'll have a think and see if there's anything else I can think of and edit accordingly, otherwise will delete (edit: accepted? I don't even know anymore... haha)

Comment: This is a bit of a disaster. Now the OP has accepted an incorrect answer because it wasn't deleted early enough.

Comment: Did using `function updateAuction() {}` fix the issue then? Yes, I don't quite get what's happening.

Answer (score -3):

You must define your function befor try. correct it like this

```
var updateAuction = function(data) {
    console.log("UPDATE AUCTIONS!");
    ...
}

try {
            Auction.deployed().then(function(contractInstance) {
                contractInstance.startAuction(auctionname, duration, { from: buyerAddress }).then(function(result) {
                    console.log("AUCTION HAS STARTED!!");
                    console.log(result);
                    updateAuction(result.receipt);
                });
            });
        } catch (err) {}
    ;
```

Comment: Those braces don't match.

Comment: yeah yeah. sorry, i've just copied it's code. last brace must be revomed

Comment: Defining the function beforehand doesn't make any difference since the `then` callback is asynchronous, and `var`s are hoisted so that they will be in scope.

Comment: @layekams Those non-matching braces suggest that in the OPs code the function was called inside another function as well.

Comment: @bergi, yeah it was the two last braces.

Comment: @4castle yeah you are right. but it is just that we don't know how he want to use it. anyway, this function must be know before execution, or it will not work.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, where `updateAuction` was being called synchronously, yes it wouldn't work, but since `updateAuction` is being called from inside a function that was passed to `then`, it will be executed asynchronously, so it doesn't matter what order the functions are defined in.

Comment: @4castle - there is of course the possibility, however small, that their promise library is being run in synchronous mode... hard to tell from the code provided.

Answer (score -3):

```
var updateAuction = function(data) {
    console.log("UPDATE AUCTIONS!");
    ...
}

try {
            Auction.deployed().then(function(contractInstance) {
                contractInstance.startAuction(auctionname, duration, { from: buyerAddress }).then(function(result) {
                    console.log("AUCTION HAS STARTED!!");
                    console.log(result);
                    updateAuction(result.receipt);
                });
            });
        } catch (err) {}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your original answer instead of posting multiple answers with essentially the same content.